# How to get postcss-nesting and @vue/cli pwa working?

Tags: postcss, vue-cli-3

How is it possible to get `postcss-nesting` and a `@vue/cli v3` project built with the PWA plugin working?

So far I've tried

`npm install postcss-nesting`

I then created a `src/main.css` which contains

```
body {
    h1 {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

Inside the `main.js` file I import the css `import './main.css';`

Then inside the `postcss.config.js` I've added it to the plugins (with others that work) e.g.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'postcss-nesting': {},
  }
}
```

When I then run `npm run serve` the CSS does not transform into `body h1` as you can see

[image: chrome dev tools]

What would be the correct way to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nesting should be enabled inside `package.json` since vue-cli does not read the configuration from `postcss.config.js` or `.postcssrc.js` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/852#issuecomment-387732065).

```
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {},
      "postcss-preset-env": {
        "browsers": "last 2 versions",
        "features": {
          "nesting-rules": true,
          "custom-media-queries": true,
          "color-mod-function": true
        }
      }
    }
},
```

Working example on this repository: https://github.com/dobladov/vue-cli-example-postcss

Also for the nesting is important to use the symbol `&`

```
<style>
    body {
      background-color: tomato;
      & .foo {
        color: purple;
      }
    }
 </style>
```

Comment: "should" would be lovely if it worked  I've replaced the content of `postcss.config.js` with just `module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'postcss-preset-env': {
      browsers: 'last 2 versions',
      features: {
        'nesting-rules': true,
        'custom-media-queries': true,
        'color-mod-function': true,
      },
    },
  },
};` and its still outputting the same - which lead me to believe i must have missed something else

Comment: Sorry, you are right, my last response was a valid configuration but not for vue-cli, I edited the answer with the solution and a repository with a working example, let me know if this fixes your problem.